# What does it mean when something uses two -> operators in php?

Tags: php

I'm looking at some code here and there are bunch of calls that are like this. I don't have much experience with php, mainly java. Is this like if I had a Dog object that had a fur object and I wanted to call "dog.getFur().getColor();" ?

Example:

```
  $this->tbtemp_list1->lead_time = ($this->add_lead_time->Text + $this->add_transit_time->Text);
  $this->tbtemp_list1->units = $this->add_units->Text;
  $this->tbtemp_list1->item_class = $this->txtClass->Value;
  $this->tbtemp_list1->category = $this->add_part_category->Text;
  $this->tbtemp_list1->description = $this->add_part_description->Text;
  $this->tbtemp_list1->notes = $this->txtNotes->Text;
```

Comment: You are accessing a sub-object. So the first line `$this->tbtemp_list1` is an object, and you are accessing the `lead_time` property of that object.

Comment: *(related)* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`->` (arrow) is [object notation in PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php).

It's equivalent is the `.` (dot) object notation Java.

For example:

```
// PHP
$this->tbtemp_list1->lead_time
```

is:

```
// Java
this.tbtemp_list1.lead_time
```

In this case, you are reference a property (`lead_time`) that is a property of an object `lead_time` which is a property of an object (`$this`). This can go on *forever* provided the property is an object.

Comment: Glad you found this helpful. Ironically my answer was originally deleted by **Robert Harvey**.

Answer (score 2):

You are right in your thinking, the -> operator simply accesses a member of an object, such that in `$this->tbtemp_list1->lead_time` the tbtemp_list1 member of the current object is being accessed, and then the lead_time member of the tbtemp_list1 member.

Answer (score 2):

in php

a->b->c  is accessing c which is a property or method of b, and b is a child object of a.  In javascript, you're just method chaining.

Comment: Not really familiar with javascript, just java.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this like if I had a Dog object that had a fur object and I wanted
>   to call "dog.getFur().getColor();" ?

Yes. The "->" operator in PHP is similar to the "->" operator in C.

In C, it gets a member from a pointer. In PHP, it gets a member from a reference. Since PHP is written in C, I suspect that the syntax for accessing members from objects was directly borrowed from C.

Edit:
It's also good to note here that [static](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) members require a different syntax.

```
print className::$staticVariable;
```

Comment: Nice addition wrt the static member access syntax